# CSS is acting funny

Tags: css, line

I have a simple question, but I have been breaking my head for 3 hours now. I am using a now-playing script in my header. I want all words on the same height. That's not what happening now. I see the artist and then the title in not on the same line as the artist is. No, the title is much more left (see picture).

[image]

This is my CSS

```
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
font-family: 'Roboto Consensed',sans-serif;
```

You can take a look  [here](http://www.FavoriteFM.com)

What can I do about it?

Comment: Create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on a site like [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). As it stands, this question doesn't have enough info to properly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `left: 10px;` on your `<div class="np_label">` and use `margin-left: 40px;` instead. This will tell the block to start at 40px offset to the left and thus will break words with said offset.